# Connect to SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I'm a beginner programmer with C#. I'm trying to develop an application that it connects to a database and do the typical operations like insert, delete, update and get.

I'm getting a error with the database connection. I'm working with SQL Server 2012, where I have create a database called `company`.

This is my code:

```
namespace DAL
{
    public class DAL
    {
        public const string CADENA_CONEXION = "Data Source=localhost;" +
            "Initial Catalog=Company" +
            "Integrated Security=false" +
            "UID=root PWD=root";
        public SqlConnection con;
        public SqlCommand command;

    public DAL()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = CADENA_CONEXION;
    }

    public Boolean addEmployee(Employee emp)
    {
        try
        {
            /*String sqlInsertString = "INSERT INTO Employee (FirstName, LastName, ID, " + 
           "Designation) VALUES ("+e.firstName+","+ e.lastName+","+e.empCode+","+e.designation+")";*/
            string sqlInsertString =
                "INSERT INTO Employee (FirstName, LastName, ID, " +
                "Designation) VALUES (@firstName, @lastName, @ID, @designation)";
            command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection.Open();
            command.CommandText = sqlInsertString;

            SqlParameter firstNameparam = new SqlParameter("@firstName", emp.FirstName);
            SqlParameter lastNameparam = new SqlParameter("@lastName", emp.LastName);
            SqlParameter IDparam = new SqlParameter("@ID", emp.EmpCode);
            SqlParameter designationParam = new SqlParameter("@designation", emp.Designation);

            command.Parameters.AddRange(new SqlParameter[]{
            firstNameparam,lastNameparam,IDparam,designationParam});

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.Connection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
            throw;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

What is the error? I get an exception on this line:

```
command.Connection.Open();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the exception message exactly?

Comment: When I see your connection string it's like you want to connect to a Mysql database and not a SQL Server one, can you give more specification

Comment: open the connection first, then create the command

Comment: also assign the connection to the command!!

Comment: `command.Connection.Open()` is going to fail with a NullReferenceException as you have not assigned a `SqlConnection` object to the command's `Connection` property but you are trying to call open on it.

Comment: Your `catch` section will cause you problems as the exception is never re-thrown because you return before control reaches that line.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String Goes here");
```

You should assign connection to SqlCommand object like this

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.Connection = con;
```

or

```
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("YourQuery",con);
```

**Some Important Steps to Execute Command**

> 1: Create SqlConnection Object and Assign a connection string to that object

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String Goes here");
```

or

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.Connection = "Your Connection String Goes here";
```

> 2: Create SqlCommand Object and assing a command Text(Your Query) and connection string to that object

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from Products",con);
```

or

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.Connection = con;
command.CommandText ="Select * from Products";
```

You can also specify CommandType

```
command.CommandType =CommandType.Text; 
/* if you are executing storedprocedure CommandType Will be
  => CommandType.StoredProcedure; */
```

then You can Execute Command Like this

```
 try 
 {
  con.Open();
  int TotalRowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
 catch(Exeception ex)
 {
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
 finaly
 {
  con.Close();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

not initialize sqlcommand connections, way for initialize this is :

```
command.Connection=con;
```

this is complete code for you :

```
namespace DAL
{
    public class DAL
    {
        public const string CADENA_CONEXION = "Data Source=localhost;" +
            "Initial Catalog=Company" +
            "Integrated Security=false" +
            "UID=root PWD=root";
        public SqlConnection con;
        public SqlCommand command;

    public DAL()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = CADENA_CONEXION;
    }

    public Boolean addEmployee(Employee emp)
    {
        try
        {
            /*String sqlInsertString = "INSERT INTO Employee (FirstName, LastName, ID, " + 
           "Designation) VALUES ("+e.firstName+","+ e.lastName+","+e.empCode+","+e.designation+")";*/
            string sqlInsertString =
                "INSERT INTO Employee (FirstName, LastName, ID, " +
                "Designation) VALUES (@firstName, @lastName, @ID, @designation)";
            command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection=con;
            command.Connection.Open();
            command.CommandText = sqlInsertString;

            SqlParameter firstNameparam = new SqlParameter("@firstName", emp.FirstName);
            SqlParameter lastNameparam = new SqlParameter("@lastName", emp.LastName);
            SqlParameter IDparam = new SqlParameter("@ID", emp.EmpCode);
            SqlParameter designationParam = new SqlParameter("@designation", emp.Designation);

            command.Parameters.AddRange(new SqlParameter[]{
            firstNameparam,lastNameparam,IDparam,designationParam});

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.Connection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
            throw;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had all the changes you wrote. Now, I get this exception message: Error of init session of the user = ' '

Comment: use this connection string:   public const string CADENA_CONEXION = "Data Source=localhost;" +
            "Initial Catalog=Company" +
            "Integrated Security=true" ;

Comment: I have modified the connection string, but i get the same message exception

Comment: Please check your host name in connection string for example :"FATHI-PC" in your sql server management

Comment: YeS yes, there was a mistake about this. I solved it, but the problem is the same. I get the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI: An alternative to the try finally blocks, which ensure the database connection gets closed is to use the using statement such as:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
       connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        //log and/or rethrow or ignore
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        //log and/or rethrow or ignore
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        //log and/or rethrow or ignore
    }
}
```

Refer to the MSDN documentation for the SqlCommand class here, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx, and look up the [ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)() method, which is used to execute INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements.  Then look up [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)() method that you can use to execute SELECT statements that return a single value.  You can use [ExecuteReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx)() to return a SqlDataReader for SELECT statements that return multiple columns.